# Define (not use default) for shapes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes

I am trying to make a scatterplot with three shapes (small circle, large circle, and cross).

I am able to get to the point where I have almost what I want, except that I can't figure out how to specify the shapes:

```
AData=as.data.frame(cbind(x=rnorm(5, 10, 1),y=rnorm(5,10,1)))
AData["Type"] = rep(1,dim(AData)[1])
BData=as.data.frame(cbind(x=rnorm(5, 20, 1),y=rnorm(5,20,1)))
BData["Type"] = rep(2,dim(BData)[1])
CData=as.data.frame(t(c(0,0,3)))
colnames(AData) = c("Ankle.dif", "Knee.dif", "Type")
colnames(BData) = c("Ankle.dif", "Knee.dif", "Type")
colnames(CData) = c("Ankle.dif", "Knee.dif", "Type")
dataFramePlot = rbind(AData, BData, CData)
ggplot(dataFramePlot, aes(x=Ankle.dif, y=Knee.dif)) + geom_point(aes(shape = factor(Type)))
```

I get a circle, triangle, and square here, but I prefer to specify a small circle, large circle, and crossbar for the three types. Any ideas? THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `scale_shape_manual`. For shape, you can find more information in many places. Here is a [link](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape) for you. As the OP requested in the comment below, I modified the legend.

```
ggplot(dataFramePlot, aes(x=Ankle.dif, y=Knee.dif)) +
geom_point(aes(shape = factor(Type)))+
scale_shape_manual(name = "Data",
                   values=c(20, 19, 3),
                   breaks=c("1", "2", "3"),
                   labels=c("First data", "Second data", "Third data"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jazzurro: How would I change the factor(Type) label specifically, so that instead of listing "1", "2", and "3", I can create three string labels?

Comment: @JosephHudson What label do you want instead of the numbers?

Comment: Thanks @jazzurro: I want the three labels to be, say, "First data", "Second data", "Third data"

Comment: @JosephHudson I revised my answer. Now you have the legend you want. Please have a look.